# Multiple Columns in listview

Tags: c#, winforms, listview, listbox, listviewitem

I am writing the following code in C# to show data in multiple columns in a listView but it only shows the first element of the array,

```
ListViewItem item = new ListViewItem(new []{txtTitle.Text,txtRatings.Value.ToString(),cmbGenre.Text});
lstMovie.Items.Add(item);
```

the output in the list view is just the first element. How do I get all three elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The data was inserted but listview was not displaying it, set listView's View property to Details

```
lstView.View = View.Details;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the 3 columns to your listview before trying to populate it?  Something like:

```
lstMovie.Columns.Add("Title");
lstMovie.Columns.Add("Ratings");
lstMovie.Columns.Add("Genre");
```

Comment: Yes figured it out, I had to set my list.view to details
lstMovie.View = View.Details