# Bind data from values in Class to ListView

Tags: c#, database, class, listview

I'm writing this application in which data is currently shown in a listbox, using the string values from a class. But I decided that I want to have my data shown in a ListView. However, I don't know how to do so.

So the idea is: I have - obviously - a Form, I have a Database class that pulls data from my database and I have a class that holds the values. Its output is this:

```
return _Productnaam + " - " + _HoudbaarheidsDatum + " - " + _Locatie;
```

How do I manage to get those individual values correctly in an ListView object, that has three columns? I know how to actually put data into a ListView, but not when I work with multiple return values.

I hope the description of my problem is a bit clear, and anyone can help me out with this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple Columns in listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12467557/multiple-columns-in-listview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets assume you have a `listView`, and a list of `Products`. You can do it as follows:

```
listView.View = View.Details;
listView.GridLines = true; //same ways set up other props accordingly

//now add columns
listView.Columns.Add("Name", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView.Columns.Add("Houdbaarheids Datum", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);
listView.Columns.Add("Locatie", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left);

for (int i = 0; i < products.Count; i++)
{
      // Define the list items
      ListViewItem prd = new ListViewItem(products[i].Name);
      prd.SubItems.Add(products[i]._HoudbaarheidsDatum);
      prd.SubItems.Add(products[i]._Locatie);

      // Add the list items to the ListView
      listView.Items.Add(prd);
}
```

Comment: And what if it's not a list, but simply a class that the data has got to come from? Thing is, I cannot refer to my class using the Count thing. So it doesn't work in my case.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. You would actually have a list of your class type. For example `var products = new List<Product>();` . Then insert your products in this list from what you are referring as `simple class`. no matter if it is one item or more. If still not clear, please share your code

Comment: My bad, did not realize I used the wrong 'call' to class. xD Anyway, it works! Thank you mate, really appreciate it!